# Firebase conflict with FB SDK Login

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, firebase, fbsdkloginkit

I am recently found one update that need to integrate Firebase for crash reporting analytics, along side previously implemented Facebook login. I have implemented FB login with FBSDKLoginButton, and works superb.

But when I uncomment `[FIRApp configure]` on `appdelegate` it stopping to handle `application:openURL:options:`, I am 100% sure about FB login implementation, As I said It works fine if I comments  `[FIRApp configure]`.

Here is the code for reference:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
      BOOL b = [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];
      [FIRApp configure]; //If I comment this, works fine with FB callback which handles at application:openURL:options:
      return b;
}

-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)app
       openURL:(NSURL *)url
       options:(NSDictionary<UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey,id> *)options {

       BOOL handled = [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:app
                                                              openURL:url
                                                    sourceApplication:options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsSourceApplicationKey]
                                                           annotation:options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsAnnotationKey]];
     return handled;
}

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {
     [FBSDKAppEvents activateApp];
}
```

As soon we uncomment Firebase configuration method, FB Call back changes to following backtrace :

> -[ViewController loginButton:didCompleteWithResult:error:]
>
> -[FBSDKLoginButton _buttonPressed:]_block_invoke
>
> -[FBSDKLoginManager invokeHandler:error:]
>
> -[FBSDKLoginManager(Native) handleImplicitCancelOfLogIn]
>
> -[FBSDKApplicationDelegate applicationDidBecomeActive:]

**Update**

The Problem is with **`[FIRApp configure]`,** so please suggest solution where case same.

Comment: Can you tell me exactly what you trying to do only facebook login or facebook login with firebase ?

Comment: Separate, facebook login and firebase for crash and analytic

Comment: In my project, even commenting FirebaseApp.configure() doesn't solve the issue. Facebook Login gives error: com.facebook.sdk.core error 3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Or you can disable it with FirebaseAppDelegateProxy. In info.plist paste FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled with value NO.

Comment: What is the first option available, as you mentioned or?

Comment: @ViralSavaj "...paste the reversegoogle key in url types..."

Comment: 'adding reversegoogle key in url types' works on debug build but it doesn't work on release build. Any idea why?

Comment: @ViralSavaj what exactly solved the problem? Please can you explain? Thanks, suffer from the same conflict

Answer (score 2):

Please check this.

In your Project goto ->Info and you need to paste the reversegoogle key in url types,May be thats the mistake you are doing,Just paste the code in appdelegate

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
            openURL:(NSURL *)url
  sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication
         annotation:(id)annotation {
    if ([url.scheme hasPrefix:@"fb"]){
        return [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application
                                                              openURL:url
                                                    sourceApplication:sourceApplication
                                                           annotation:annotation];
    }else{
        return [[GIDSignIn sharedInstance] handleURL:url
                                   sourceApplication:sourceApplication
                                          annotation:annotation];
    }
}
```

Comment: reversegoogle key? where can I find it, and what is use of it in this problem?

Comment: You have Google plist right?Check there you can find ReverseClientID which will be like this com.googleusercontent.apps.6196***************************1

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how my solution is related to the OP, but my conflict between Facebook Login and Firebase has been solved by putting this in my pod file:

```
pod 'FBSDKCoreKit', '4.38.1'
pod 'FBSDKLoginKit', '4.38.1'
```

As described here: https://github.com/facebook/facebook-swift-sdk/issues/298